# Minimization with respect to functional constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to do the following on Mathematica:
Given a pair $(x,y)$, minimize an objective function $f(x,z)$ such that z satisfies $g(x,z) \leq g(x,y)$.

I have defined both functions

```
f[x_, y_] := ...

g[x_, y_] := ...
```

Tried the following but it did not work:

```
x = a number;
y = another number

Min[{f[x, z], g[x, z] <= g[x, y]}, {z, 1, 10}]
```

Could you help me on that please?

Comment: 1. The minimization functions are `FindMinimum[]` and `NMinimize[]`; none of those are in what you've written. 2. You should include the actual functions if you want people to be more helpful.

Comment: Ups I've done a mistake, thanks! I will prepare my question better and ask again.

Answer (score 1):

```
FindMinimum[{f[x, z], g[x, z] <= g[x, y]}, z][[1]]
```